# Closing connection in GET request using Jersey Client 2.22.1

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am using Jersey client for REST calls from Java code:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

In my GET request,

```java
javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation.Builder builder = ClientBuilder.newClient().target(url).request(); 
builder.get().readEntity(String.class);
```

the client will be closed *automatically* after calling `readEntity(String.class)`.

If I use,

```java
builder.get(String.class);
```

I get the same output.

Is the connection closed automatically or do I need to close it manually in this case?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Short answer

Consider the following code:

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
String result = client.target(url).request().get(String.class);
```

Under the hood, Jersey invokes [`Response#readEntity(Class<T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity-java.lang.Class-) if the request has succeeded and the connection will be closed for you. *So the connection doesn't need to be closed manually in this situation.*

Now consider the following code:

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Response response = client.target(url).request().get();
```

For this situation, you need to invoke [`Response#close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#close--) to close the connection. Or invoke [`Response#readEntity(Class<T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity-java.lang.Class-) to make Jersey close the connection for you.

### Long answer

As stated in the [documentation](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e5255), if you don't [read the entity](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity-java.lang.Class-), then you need to close the response manually by invoking [`Response#close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#close--).

For more details, have a look at Jersey's [documentation](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e5255) about how to close connections:

> [**5.7. Closing connections**](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e5255)
>
> The underlying connections are opened for each request and closed
>   after the response is received and entity is processed (entity is
>   read). See the following example:
>
> ```java
> final WebTarget target = ... some web target
> Response response = target.path("resource").request().get();
> System.out.println("Connection is still open.");
> System.out.println("string response: " + response.readEntity(String.class));
> System.out.println("Now the connection is closed.");
> ```
>
> If you don't read the entity, then you need to close the response
>   manually by [`response.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#close--).
>
> Also if the entity is read into an
>   [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) (by `response.readEntity(InputStream.class)`), the
>   connection stays open until you finish reading from the [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html).
>   In that case, the [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) or the [`Response`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) should be closed
>   manually at the end of reading from [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html).

Additionally, have a look at [`JerseyInvocation` source](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.21.1/core-client/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyInvocation.java). The most important parts are quoted below.

In the `translate(ClientResponse, RequestScope, Class<T>)` method you'll see that `response.readEntity(Class<T>)` is invoked.

#### [`JerseyInvocation.Builder#get(Class<T>)`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyInvocation.Builder.html#get(java.lang.Class))

Invoke HTTP `GET` method for the current request synchronously.

```java
@Override
public <T> T get(final Class<T> responseType)
    throws ProcessingException, WebApplicationException {

    return method("GET", responseType);
}
```

#### [`JerseyInvocation.Builder#method(String, Class<T>)`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyInvocation.Builder.html#method(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class))

Invoke an arbitrary method for the current request synchronously.

```java
@Override
public <T> T method(final String name, final Class<T> responseType)
    throws ProcessingException, WebApplicationException {

    // responseType null check omitted for brevity

    requestContext.setMethod(name);
    return new JerseyInvocation(this).invoke(responseType);
}
```

#### [`JerseyInvocation#invoke(Class<T>)`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyInvocation.html#invoke(java.lang.Class))

Synchronously invoke the request and receive a response of the specified type back.

```java
@Override
public <T> T invoke(final Class<T> responseType)
    throws ProcessingException, WebApplicationException {

    // responseType null check omitted for brevity

    final ClientRuntime runtime = request().getClientRuntime();
    final RequestScope requestScope = runtime.getRequestScope();

    return requestScope.runInScope(new Producer<T>() {

        @Override
        public T call() throws ProcessingException {

            try {

                return translate(runtime.invoke(requestForCall(requestContext)), 
                                 requestScope, responseType);

            } catch (final ProcessingException ex) {
                // Exception handling omitted for brevity
            }
        }
    });
}
```

#### `JerseyInvocation#translate(ClientResponse, RequestScope, Class<T>)`

If the request suceeded, the response entity is read as an instance of specified Java type using [`Response#readEntity(Class<T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity-java.lang.Class-):

```java
private <T> T translate(final ClientResponse response, final RequestScope scope, 
    final Class<T> responseType) throws ProcessingException {

    if (responseType == Response.class) {
        return responseType.cast(new InboundJaxrsResponse(response, scope));
    }

    if (response.getStatusInfo().getFamily() == Response.Status.Family.SUCCESSFUL) {

        try {

            return response.readEntity(responseType);

        } catch (final ProcessingException ex) {
            // Exception handling omitted for brevity
        }

    } else {
        throw convertToException(new InboundJaxrsResponse(response, scope));
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that connection will be closed after `readEntity()` I mentioned in my quesiton. I am asking for `Builder.get(String.class)`

Comment: you should modify your answer as  current answer does not serve the need.